# How can I find company address with Company Name, zip codes and State of Existence?

Tags: software-recommendations, united-states, address, zip-codes, service-recommendations

I need to find the address of the companies located in a particular State with Company name and also zip codes.

**Example**:

> **Company Name:** Integrated Care Management

Within the following zip codes in **GA** -

```
30062, 30319, 30338, 30005, 30022, 30075, 30076, 30092, 30004
```

**Steps**:-

1. Currently I googling the company name and search for the address in Google maps.
2. Sometimes will find their company website and take the address from it. For the above example I have mentioned, I found the following address through google maps

   **Addresss**:- 3440 Preston Ridge Road
   Alpharetta, GA 30005

How can I get this done easily for more companies. Is there any website or tool to make it quite easy and less time consuming?

Comment: In the united states only?

Comment: @BradHards Yes in the United States only.

Answer (score 2):

We call them local business directory. There are several sites that constantly lists all business listing in an area. e.g. Yellow pages, Yelp, Craiglist etc. Some googled result is as below--

For Yellow pages see shot-

[image]

[1. http://local-business-directory-review.toptenreviews.com/](http://local-business-directory-review.toptenreviews.com/)

[2. http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/10322/The-Ultimate-List-50-Local-Business-Directories.aspx](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/10322/The-Ultimate-List-50-Local-Business-Directories.aspx)

[3. http://www.dmoz.org/](http://www.dmoz.org/)